# Receiving "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() could not receive data from server: Connection timed out" in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, postgresql, activerecord, pgbouncer

In my rake task, I'm connecting to postgresql via a pgbouncer setup. For **some queries** I receive this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() could not receive data from server: Connection timed out
```

In my pgbouncer log, I see this entry:

```
closing because: client unexpected eof (age=3110)
```

I have disabled prepared statements in my `config/database.yml` file and enabled `transaction` `pool_mode` in my pgbouncer config file.
When I directly connect to postgres, I don't get this error.

Also in my rake task, I am creating multiple threads. I tried running `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!` inside my threads as suggested [here](http://ruby.zigzo.com/2012/01/29/the-parallel-gem-and-postgresql-oh-and-rails/). That didn't help either.

I am using rails version 4.2.5 which has [this fix](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a456acb2f2af8365eb9151c7cd2d5a10c189d191). I'm still getting this error "could not receive data from server: Connection timed out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused due to network issues in clients. Not able to reproduce since we migrated both server and client to Google Cloud Platform. Earlier our server was in DigitalOcean while our clients were in GCP.